# Trying to make an AFK command using change nickname

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command that changes the nickname of the person when they type afk on then the bot adds AFK to there nickname. When they type afk off its removes AFK from there name.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.includes('changeNick')) {
        client.setNickname({nick: message.content.replace('changeNick', '')});
    }
});
```

I reffered to this code however it doesn't work. Also is there anyway you can reset nickname back when a user types changenickoff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `Member#setNickname`:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.includes('start-afk')) {
        message.member.setNickname(`${message.author.username} [AFK]`);
    }
    if (message.content.includes('end-afk')) {
        message.member.setNickname('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

- Does the user's nickname already start with `[AFK]` ?

  - IF yes, remove it.

    - notify user

      - end
- ELSE: add `[AFK]` to their nickname

  - notify user

    - end

You were doing `client.setNickname`, which, to my knowledge, wouldn't work since the `client` is not a `GuildMember` instance.

It's worth noting that a `GuildMember` is verry different to a Discord `User`. GuildMembers have access to roles and permissions; users do not.

- You can view exactly what a `User` structure is by doing `console.log(client.users.cache.get(message.author.id))`

Here's the amended code.
*Additionally, I have included a function that trims a string to ensure it does not exceed X chars in length.*

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    //function to trim strings, ensuring they don't exceed X chars in length
    trimStr = (str, max) => ((str.length > max) ? `${str.slice(0, max - 3)}...` : str);

    if (message.guild) /* Ensure message is in a server; */ {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!afk')) {
            const nick = message.member.nickname;
            if (nick.startsWith('[AFK]')) {
                //remove nick and notify user:
                message.member.setNickname(null);
                message.reply("Welcome back, I've removed your AFK status.");
            } else { //If above condition is false:
                //add [AFK] to the new nick along with the nickname
                //trim new string to ensure it's not longer than 32 characters since Discord limits this. 
                const newNickname = trimStr(`[AFK] ${nick.length ? nick : message.author.username}`, 32);
                message.member.setNickname(newNickname);
                message.reply("Ight mate, I've set your AFK!");
            };
        };
    };
});
```

If there are any errors, please provide them in full detail (stacktrace and error itself) in the comments so I can be of further assistance to you.

**NOTE** - You'll need to type `!afk` in order to trigger this code.